# ID not replaced by %s in python django

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

```
def read_lf_notifiation(request, id, slug):
    lf = LostAndFound.objects.get(slug=slug)
    notf = N_lostandfound.objects.get(id=id, lf=lf)
    if notf.read == False:
       notf.read = True
       notf.save()
    return HttpResponseRedirect('/lostandfound/%s/?notif_id=%s' %(slug, notf.id))
```

So read_lf_notification is supposed to read the notfication and redirect to the same page but with the url parameter of notif_id. So I want to give the value of notif_id, the id of notf, but when it redirects to the same page, the response is
http://localhost:8000/this-is-slug/?notf_id=id

But what I want is 
http://localhost:8000/this-is-slug/?notf_id=12

What am I doing wrong here?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Try using `%d` instead of `%s` for `id`.

Comment: try using **format** instead `'/lostandfound/{slug}/?notif_id={id}'.format(slug, notf.id)`

Comment: okay thanks guys. Both worked.